# Three wheeler pulls to left when riding

Tags: maintenance, tricycle

Why does my three wheeler pull to side when riding. Especially if I go over a bump it will go to the left by itself.

Comment: Two wheels in back, with the chain driving the shaft between the two wheels?  Are both wheels connected to the shaft or is one free to rotate on the shaft?

Comment: You're almost certainly going to have to give more information than this. If there's nothing more you can say, you'll probably have to take it to a bike shop and let them look at it.

Comment: Daniel R Hicks, David Richerby. Thank you for your responses.  I really don't know what I can add about the bike. I think I'll just have to take to the bike shop.

Comment: Look at the chain!   What wheels does it drive???

Answer (score 1):

Trikes with fork rake lean to the right on the camber of the road. They naturally try to steer left as the trail of the front wheel's castor forces it so. At least in drive on right side of the road countries. PIA. See if it wants to steer the other way if you ride it on the wrong side of the road. If doesn't cancel out you've got something bent.

Answer (score 0):

From your limited description it sounds like the left rear wheel is slowing and pulling the trike to the side. I would think this is caused by unintended friction, especially since you state that it worsens when going over a bump. I'd check for any rubbing brakes or guards on that side if you haven't already. It might even be a bearing problem, though I imagine if it were bad enough to pull noticeably you'd probably be hearing noises from it too.